# XMLRequest ResponseText is blank

Tags: javascript, xmlhttprequest

I've got a JavaScript function that I want to report an alert message to the users if it successfully updates the database, or if it has an error.

In the main X.JSP file I have:

```
function startRequest(pChange)
        {

                //alert("startRequest");
                createXmlHttpRequest();
                //alert("sending message");
                //var u1=document.f1.user.value;
                //alert("Running startRequest for: " + pChange.id);
                //xmlHttp.open("GET","updateEntry.jsp&pID=pChange.id&pStatus=pChange.status&pAddress=pChange.address&pDate=pChange.date&pNotes=pChange.note&pAssigned=pChange.assigned" ,true)
                xmlHttp.open("GET","updateEntry.jsp?pID=" + pChange.id + "&pAddress=" +pChange.address + "&pStatus=" + pChange.status +"&pNote=" + pChange.notes +"&pAssigned=" +pChange.assigned ,true)
                //alert(xmlHttp.responseText);
                xmlHttp.onreadystatechange=handleStateChange;
                xmlHttp.send(null);           
        }
function handleStateChange()
        {
            //alert("handleStateChange");
            var message = xmlHttp.responseText;
            alert("Return Code:" + message);
            if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
            {
                if(xmlHttp.status==200)
                {
                    //alert("test2");
                    //alert("recieved Message");
                    var message = xmlHttp.responseText;
                    alert(message);
                }
            }
            else
            {
                alert("Error loading page"+ xmlHttp.status +
            ":"+xmlHttp.statusText);
            }
        }
```

I then run a method in updateEntry.jsp that does a number of things, but of interest is this section:

```
if(nId.equals("NMI")||nId.equals("MI")||nId.equals("NI")||nId.equals("SA")||nId.equals("S"))
            {
                org.hibernate.Query query2 = session2.createQuery("update Leads set Status = :nstatus where Id = :nid");
                query2.setParameter("nid", nId);
                query2.setParameter("nstatus", nstatus);
                query2.executeUpdate();
                out.println("Update successfully with: " + nstatus);
                // Actual contact insertion will happen at this step
                session2.flush();
                session2.close();
            }
            else
            {   
                out.println("Status must be: NMI, MI, NI, SA or S");        
            }
```

My understanding is that this should only create a single alert, if the function completes successfully. Instead it creates like 9 alerts all of which are blank. What am I doing wrong? I'm seeing both the "Return Code: " message and a blank " " message, (two different sections of code) but both output blank message variables.

Answer (score 0):

If the readystate is not 4, it does not mean it is an error. Ajax has multiple states that inform the clientside about what is happening. Your code says that those connection states are all errors.

```
        if(xmlHttp.readyState==4)
        {
            if(xmlHttp.status==200)
            {
                //alert("test2");
                //alert("recieved Message");
                var message = xmlHttp.responseText;
                alert(message);
            }  <-- your else should most likely be up here
        }
        else  <-- this is incorrect
        {
            alert("Error loading page"+ xmlHttp.status +
        ":"+xmlHttp.statusText);
        }
```

Read the document at [MDN - Ajax Getting Started](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started)

Comment: Yes, I'll agree with you on that, but that's not really the problem I'm looking to address. Why can't I pass along messages into the xmlHttp.reponseText?

Comment: It expalains all of the alerts. Have you looked at what is being returned from the server. Use a tool like Fiddler or Firebug to look at the request.